# how to avoid checking mobile during work?

Tags: time

I don't know whether does it happen to others or not, but I check my mobile in each 15-30 minutes interval. It is not a problem if I do in my free time, but it is a big problem if I continue during my work. I too understand that it is a bad habit and greatly disturbs my concentrations of doing good work. Sometimes I too feel very bad when I think about it, but I repeat again after few hours. I mostly check Facebook, WatsApp, Skype and Emails.

So I am wondering is there is any way to get rid of this? I would also like to mention that I am not a such reputed/big person who always gets some updates in his/her mobile.

Comment: If you want to stop, just stop doing it then. If you really can't refrain, search for professional advice cause that's an addiction you have... I would also be concerned about doing it during my free time. At least I find it a bit rude when friends do it to me.

Comment: Welcome to the site. Unfortunately, these types of habit transformation and self improvement tips aren't really withing the scope of this site. See [What topics can I ask about here?](http://lifehacks.stackexchange.com/help/on-topic). Sorry about the confusion.

Comment: get rid of your smartphone and buy a dumb phone and a separate tablet instead, leave the tablet at home, don't take it to work. You're suffering from technophilia, and its a common problem.... I know someone who checked her phone every 2 minutes, even while reading to her son at bedtime - and this was her solution and saviour.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It's probably not an addiction so much as a habit.  Put your phone in a drawer rather than on your desk, then keep a stress ball or spare pen or anything to keep your hands busy.

Comment: Turn the sound off or turn the thing off all together. Have a special time - in your lunch hour - when you check it and then put it away again. Tell your friends you are doing this so they will not be worried.